# How to create model with relationship one-to-many in Django?

Tags: django

I need create relationship one-to-many.
One Group can have many members.

Did I do it right?

Model:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    groupName: models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description: models.CharField(max_length=255)
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updatedAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    members: models.ForeignKey(User, n_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ForeignKey` represents `ManyToOne` relationship so here according to your model One member will have many groups.

If you want one group will have many members then the models should be like this.

```
class Group(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    groupName: models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description: models.CharField(max_length=255)
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updatedAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Member(models.Model):
   group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
   ......
```